# The Type TOut must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter T in the generic type of method

Tags: c#

I have the generic method to parse the json response but when I tries to call it in my method I'm getting an error "  The Type TOut must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter T in the generic type of method". Please help and Let me know how to call the generic method.

```
private static T TryParse<T>(string input, T defaultVal = default(T)) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return defaultVal;
        }
    }

public async Task<Tuple<bool, string, TOut>> GetAsync<TOut>(
        Func<string, bool> successTest = null,
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        var result = await GetAsync(parameters);
        var response = await GetResponseContentAsync(result.Content);
        var responseObj = TryParse<TOut>(response);


        return Tuple.Create(true, response, responseObj);
    }
```

Comment: Your `TryParse` has a restriction `T : class`. You are not enforcing this restriction in your `GetAsync` method.

Comment: Just add `where T : class` constraint to `GetAsync` method

Comment: Hi Chris. So you mean mean need to remove the T : class ?

Answer (score 3):

Your `TryParse<T>` method says that `T` must be a class (`where T : class`). Your `GetAsync<TOut>` method lets `T` be anything - there's no restriction on it.

However, `TOut` is used as `T` when calling `TryParse`. Here's the problem - `TOut` can be anything, but `T` can only be a class.

Either remove the `where T : class` restriction from `TryParse`, or add it to `GetAsync` (`where TOut : class`). Which you do depends on your requirements.

Comment: Ohh yeah..got it now...such a big help understanding this one. Thank you so much!